# Asymmetric universal property for tensor products

Tags: ct.category-theory, higher-category-theory, tensor-products

Cartesian products have the following asymmetric description: $X\times Y=\coprod_{x\in X} Y$. I am looking for a similar description of tensor products (of abelian groups, for example).

If $A$ is an abelian group and $B_{\bullet}:A\rightarrow\text{Ab}$ a functor, write $a\otimes b$ for the element of $\bigoplus_{a\in A}B_a$ given by $b\in B_a$. Then $\bigoplus_{a\in A}B_a$ is generated by $a\otimes b$ subject to relations $a\otimes(b+b^\prime)=a\otimes b+a\otimes b^\prime$.

I also want to encode relations $(a+a^\prime)\otimes b=a\otimes b+a^\prime\otimes b$. In order for this to make sense, suppose $B_\bullet$ is an oplax monoidal functor, so that there are maps $(f_0,f_1):B_{a+a^\prime}\rightarrow B_a\oplus B_{a^\prime}$. Define $$A\otimes B_\bullet=(\bigoplus_{a\in A}B_a)/[(a+a^\prime)\otimes b=a\otimes f_0(b)+a^\prime\otimes f_1(b)].$$ When $B$ is a constant functor (oplax monoidal structure given by the diagonal $\Delta:B\rightarrow B\oplus B$), this construction recovers the usual tensor product. But the application I have in mind:

- is not a constant functor, so I need the construction described above;
- takes place in $\infty$-categories, so I would prefer a universal property to this "ad hoc" definition.

**Question**: Is there some nice universal property satisfied by this construction?

Comment: You're considering $A$ as a discrete category with monoidal structure coming from the group structure? And $Ab$ is considered as monoidal under direct sum? This feels unusual... I appreciate that you've stripped down the question to its essence, but I feel myself wanting more context, actually! For instance, is it important to work with abelian groups, or would the same question about commutative monoids be equally relevant?

Comment: If the functor were lax monoidal rather than oplax, the analogous construction $A \otimes' B_\bullet$ would have the following universal property: a map $A \otimes' B_\bullet \to C$ is the same as a natural transformation of lax monoidal functors from $B_\bullet$ to the "constant" functor at $C$.

Comment: Commutative monoids would work just as well. I chose abelian groups for concreteness. The example I want is for the $\infty$-category of symmetric monoidal $\infty$-categories, and there is some added laxness (yikes). I don't think this is the appropriate venue to elaborate on that, though.

Your second comment: Does that recover the usual tensor product, though? I didn't think I could formulate this without the oplax assumption.